# Переклад рос. "состоялся" в значенні "реалізувався"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

Нещодавно натрапив на *відбутися* як переклад рос. *состояться* в реченні *он состоялся как художник*, що є явною калькою, бо жоден укр. словник не наводить такого тлумачення цього слова.

З синонімів є *ствердитися* або *реалізуватися*, але мені вони здаються такими, що неповністю передають зміст, бо *реалізуватися* одразу асоціюється із самореалізацією, тобто має фокус на тому, як людина сприймає себе, в той час як *состояться* більше фокусується на визнанні іншими представниками категорії, в якій хтось чи щось *"состоялось"*.

Чи є альтернативні слова або усталені словосполучення, за допомогою яких можна точніше передати саме цей відтінок?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Крім інших варіянтів, запропонованих тут, російське «*состоялся*» в сенсі **стати кимось**, **отримати визнання**, **проявляти себе**, **справдити очікування**, **набути форми** можна перекласти українською як:

#### Став(-ти) визнаним (як), отримав визнання як

Тут **визнаний** — який одержав загальне визнання, відомий всім або багатьом. [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyznanyj)

> ... академія Вест​Пойнт покликана «виховувати, навчати і надихати
> кадетський корпус, щоб кожен випускник **став визнаним** моральним
> авторитетом, ...
>
> У науковому світі Микита Шаповал **отримав визнання як** вчений-соціолог.
>
> Чесний перед собою і перед мистецтвом, без гонитви за заробітчанством,
> Звір у 1981 р. **отримав визнання як** мистець і розпочав викладацьку
> роботу в академії.
>
> Нападник "Барселони" і збірної Уругваю Луїс Суарес **отримав визнання
> як** найкращий гравець минулого сезону серед представників ...

#### Утвердився

**Утвердити** себе як хто, що — зміцнівши, проявити себе певним чином. [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/utverdzhuvaty)

> Михайло Возняк ніколи не виїжджав на постійне місце проживання й праці
> зі Львова — міста, де він **утвердився як** вчений та педагог.
>
> Тут він **утвердився як** людина, як столярних справ майстер, тут він
> господар.

#### Втілився

Проявлятися, здійснюватися в конкретній формі. [СУМ](http://sum.in.ua/s/vtiljuvatysja)

> Працював у Львові, вчився у Варшаві, а **втілився як** митець високої
> культури в Америці, у світі.

---

Щодо слова ***відбутися***. Як я знайшов, для відповідного речення типу «*состояться как личность/человек*» використовують слово **здійснитися**. Підозрюю воно поступається слову відбутися при перекладі, але суб'єктивно (мені) воно доречніше.

> Людина стає особистістю, проте може й не стати нею, не **здійснитися** як
> особистість.
>
> Врешті-решт, навіть якщо Україні не судилося і цього разу **здійснитися**
> як державі, і усе знову розсиплеться, як піднята крутенем вітру
> недовершена копиця ...

Answer (score 6):

Я суб'єктивно згоден з Вами щодо *«реалізувався»* — мені теж воно асоціюється більше із самосприйняттям, ніж зі сприйняттям спільнотою. Але я не можу нічим це довести, тож вважатимемо це суто моїм особистим враженням.

Я би особисто використав щось типу «[*ствердився*](//sum.in.ua/s/stverdzhuvatysja)» (хоч безпосередньо це слово не має потрібного значення в СУМ-11). Зате є слово «***[утвердитися](//sum.in.ua/s/utverdzhuvatysja)***», що, як одне зі значень, має саме закріплення суспільного сприйняття, в тому числі як виконавця певної ролі чи спеціаліста в певній діяльності:

> Установлювати свою владу, зміцнювати своє становище.
>
> **Утвердитися як** хто, що — проявити себе певним чином.
>
> > Своїми творами радянського часу Васильченко остаточно утвердився як письменник, що пише для дітей (Радянське літературознавство, 5, 1965, 59).

Якщо ж ігнорувати СУМ-11, то і «***ствердитися***» цілком підходить:

> Якщо першою книжкою Борис Олійник як поет почався, то другою він ствердився. //Абрам Кацнельсон «Про поезію [і поетів: статті, нариси, нотатки]» ([1972](//books.google.com/books?id=8Ts-AQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%22), [1977](//books.google.com/books?id=PjQMAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%22)).
>
> На весну 1997, коли я познайомився з Ігорем на одному з Ірпінських «смолоскипівських» семінарів, він ствердився як літературний критик і автор единої поки що поетичної збірки «Уласкава». //З журналу «Березіль» ([2002](//books.google.com/books?id=X-MxAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%22)).
>
> По-справжньому ж ствердився Ю. Іллєнко в режисурі у «Білому птасі з чорною ознакою» (1970) за сценарієм, написаним ним разом з І.Миколайчуком. //Василь Ілляшенко «Історія українського кіномистецтва» ([2004](//books.google.com/books?id=Wv8aAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%8F%22)).

Answer (score 5):

Гадаю, що "**реалізуватися**" може бути тим словом, яке ви шукаєте. "Он состоялся как художник" (актор, письменник, поет), але не слюсар, водій, поліціянт, в першому випадку йдеться якраз про самореалізацію, хоча з вашим фокусом я не згоден, бо рідко кажуть "я реалізувався як художник", кажуть — "він реалізувався...", то де ж тут "фокус на тому, як людина сприймає себе"?

> "Є підстави твердити, що він намагався *реалізуватися* як вузівський
> викладач-україніст – близько 1952 року читав курс стилістики
> української мови студентам редакторського факультету Українського
> поліграфічного інституту..." (МИКОЛА ЛУКАШ: МОЦАРТ УКРАЇНСЬКОГО
> ПЕРЕКЛАДУ)
>
> Тут я пригадую ім'я ще одного татарина, якого доля привела до Києва і
> де він *реалізувався*, - це художник Рафаель Багаутдінов. Його родина
> теж зазнала жорстоких репресій. (Часопис "Українська культура)
>
> Я завжди страждатиму через те, що вона не *реалізувалася* ні в
> професійному плані, ні в інтимному. (Остап Дроздов)

Ще можна вжити конструкцію типу "він **сформувався** як художник"

> ... талановитого колективу закарпатських мистців, вихований традиціями
> європейської та української культур, Тарас Данилич *сформувався* як
> художник, зріднений з дорогою його серцю закарпатською малярською
> школою.**

Якщо не хочете вживати запозичену лексику, можете сказати:
*"він **став** (справжнім, досконалим, вправним, неперевершеним) художником".*
Просто і зрозуміло:-)